# Unable to pass RBAC username of AWS Redis in ServiceStack,Redis. Does ServiceStack.Redis supports RBAC?

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, servicestack, rbac

I'm moving from AUTH to RBAC in AWS Redis and using ServiceStack.Redis package in my .NET project. But unable to pass RBAC username along with password in connectionstring inside webconfig. Does ServiceStack.Redis supports RBAC?